# Using rsync to write specific data from a complex file structure

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command

I am looking to use rsync to write log data to an external USB drive connected to a linux server.

The command below is writing all data and not just from October.

```
sudo rsync -av -r --progress --include **2018-10-** . /mnt/ext1/
```

The data I need from October can be found in various classes with varying directories.

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to SO. Unfortunately I have to vote to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming, it's about the use of a common command-line  tool.  This would be better off at https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux#

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only

Comment: @Nick: it sounds like you want to restrict the sync by date.  This link might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/538767/how-to-rsync-files-folders-from-a-specific-date-forward